# laravel throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to get something very basic running. I am used to CI and now learning Laravel 4, and their docs are not making it easy! Anyways, I am trying to create a login form and just make sure that data is posted successfully by printing it in the next form. I am getting this exception:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException

and my MemberController.php:

```
    public function index()
    {
        if (Session::has('userToken'))
        {
            /*Retrieve data of user from DB using token & Load view*/
            return View::make('members/profile');
        }else{
            return View::make('members/login');
        }
    }

    public function validateCredentials()
    {
        if(Input::post())
        {
            $email = Input::post('email');
            $password = Input::post('password');
            return "Email: " . $email . " and Password: " . $password;
        }else{
            return View::make('members/login');
        }
    }
```

and routes has:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('/members', 'MemberController@index');
Route::get('/validate', 'MemberController@validateCredentials');
```

and finally my view login.php has this form direction:

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('action' => 'MemberController@validateCredentials')); ?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which ``url`` you are getting the error?

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan dump-autoload`?

Comment: Old post but people still stumble across it -  try "composer dump-autoload". Worked for me.

Comment: @Andreyco this command it's not defined.

Answer (score 203):

You are getting that error because you are posting to a `GET` route.

I would split your routing for `validate` into a separate `GET` and `POST` routes.

**New Routes:**

```php
Route::post('validate', 'MemberController@validateCredentials');

Route::get('validate', function () {
    return View::make('members/login');
});
```

Then your controller method could just be

```php
public function validateCredentials()
{
    $email = Input::post('email');
    $password = Input::post('password');
    return "Email: " . $email . " and Password: " . $password;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

My suspicion is the problem lies in your route definition.

You defined the route as a `GET` request but the form is probably sending a `POST` request. Change your route definition to match the form's request method.

```php
Route::post('/validate', [MemberController::class, 'validateCredentials']);
```

It's generally better practice to use named routes (helps to scale if the controller method/class changes).

```php
Route::post('/validate', [MemberController::class, 'validateCredentials'])
    ->name('member.validateCredentials');
```

In the view, use the validation route as the form's action.

```
<form action="{{ route('member.validateCredentials') }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 23):

The problem is the you are using `POST` but actually you have to perform `PATCH`
To fix this add

```html
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

Just after the `Form::model` line

Comment: in Laravel you can use `{{ method_field('PATCH') }}` in your template.

Answer (score 13):

That is because you are posting data through a get method.

**Instead of**

```
Route::get('/validate', 'MemberController@validateCredentials');
```

**Try this**

```
Route::post('/validate', 'MemberController@validateCredentials');
```

Comment: This is correct, can a moderator make this the correct answer if the user isn't going to? This is the 3rd answer down and it's the only one that's right.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered this problem as well and the other answers here were helpful, but I am using a `Route::resource` which takes care of `GET`, `POST`, and other requests.

In my case I left my route as is:

```php
Route::resource('file', 'FilesController');
```

And simply modified my form to submit to the `store` function in my `FilesController`

```html
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'file.store')) }}
```

This fixed the issue, and I thought it was worth pointing out as a separate answer since various other answers suggest adding a new `POST` route.  This is an option but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 10):

Typically `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` happens when

> route method does not match.

Suppose you define `POST` request route file, but you sending `GET` request to the route.

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('action' => 'MemberController@validateCredentials')); ?>
```

by default, `Form::open()` assumes a `POST` method.

you have `GET` in your routes. change it to `POST` in the corresponding route.

or if you want to use the `GET` method, then add the `method` param.

e.g.

```
Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'get'))
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was sending a `POST` request over `HTTP` to a server where I had set up `Nginx` to redirect all requests to port `80` to port `443` where I was serving the app over `HTTPS`.

Making the request to the correct port directly fixed the problem. In my case, all I had to do is replace `http://` in the request URL to `https://` since I was using the default ports `80` and `443` respectively.

Comment: This was the problem I faced and this answer proved to be the solution. Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really fixed the issue!

Answer (score 4):

I faced the error,
problem was **FORM METHOD**

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/doctor/edit/'.$doctor->doctor_id,'class'=>'form-horizontal form-bordered form-row-stripped','method' => 'PUT','files'=>true)) }}
```

It should be like this

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/doctor/edit/'.$doctor->doctor_id,'class'=>'form-horizontal form-bordered form-row-stripped','method' => 'POST','files'=>true)) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, there is a mistake in the HTTP verb used eg:

Calling `PUT` route with `POST` request

Answer (score 2):

My problem was not that my routes were set up incorrectly, but that I was referencing the wrong `Form` method (which I had copied from a different form). I was doing...

```
{!! Form::model([ ... ]) !!}
```

(with no model specified). But I should have been using the regular `open` method...

```
{!! Form::open([ ... ]) !!}
```

Because the first parameter to `model` expect an actual model, it was not getting any of my options I was specifying. Hope this helps someone who knows their routes are correct, but something else is amiss.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same error but had a different fix, in my `XYZ.blade.php` I had:

```
{!! Form::open(array('ul' => 'services.store')) !!}
```

which gave me the error, - I still don't know why- but when I changed it to

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'services.store')) !!}
```

It worked!

I thought it was worth sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

well when i had these problem i faced 2 code errors

```
{!! Form::model(['method' => 'POST','route' => ['message.store']]) !!}
```

i corrected it by doing this

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST','route' => 'message.store']) !!}
```

so just to expatiate i changed the form `model` to `open` and also the route where wrongly placed in square braces.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel sometimes does not support `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts/store']) !!}` for security reasons. That's why the error has happened. You can solve this error by simply replacing the below code

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'posts.store')) !!}
```

Error Code `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts/store']) !!}`
Correct Code `{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'posts.store')) !!}`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because my form was sending to a route with a different middleware. So it blocked from sending information to this specific route.

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515594/pagination-doesnt-work-with-post-action-laravel-5) by  [rebduvid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6602891/rebduvid) you can use **Route::match** as below

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'results',[
        'as' => 'results_path',
        'uses' => 'SearchController@results' ]);
```

update the parameters as per your logic

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was hitting an auth protected endpoint and my auth token was invalid. Getting a new token resolved the issue. This is a new older project I'm working on so there could be something in the implementation causing this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked to check the https protocol, I in postman had defined a route with http, when the server was with https. I just corrected it and it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

```
// not done
Route::post('`/posts/{id}`', 'PostsController@store')->name('posts.store');

return redirect('`/posts'`)->with('status','Post was created !');

// done
Route::post('`/posts`', 'PostsController@store')->name('posts.store');

return redirect('`/posts'`)->with('status','Post was created !');
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little about what this code is doing and how it solves the problem?