# Laravel redirect HttpException error

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to

```
Redirect::route('some_route');
```

I'm getting this error

```
throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [laravel throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760585/laravel-throwing-methodnotallowedhttpexception)

Comment: I guess you are trying to redirect so some route that is not ```GET``` one. That's why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect::route()` sends GET request. You must have POST or some method set as the handler. Please change the route to handle GET request and you will be fine.