# Paginator displays same posts on each Page in laravel with Vue.js

Tags: pagination, vue.js, posts, laravel-5.5

**These are the *pagination links* which are displaying at the end of the page**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    {{ $posts->links("pagination::bootstrap-4") }}
    <a class="btn btn-secondary float-right" href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
</div>
```

**This is my *app.js* file using vue framework which are showing the posts**

```
let url = window.location.href;
let pageNumber = url.split('=')[1];

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        blog:{},
    },
    mounted(){
        axios.post('/getPosts',{
            'page' : pageNumber
        })
          .then(response => {
            this.blog = response.data.data
            //console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
});
```

**This is my function *getAllPosts,* but it give the same two posts on each page. I don't know why**

```
public function getAllPosts()
    {
        return $posts = post::where('status',1)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(2);
    }
```

**I am adding the images for help**
**First Page**

[image]

**Second Page**

[image]

**and third is also same! Why ?**

Comment: Laravel paginator works with GET parameters only. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515594/pagination-doesnt-work-with-post-action-laravel-5

Comment: paginator is working properly, issue is it displaying same posts on each page I don't know why as I attached the images.