# The previous button isn't working for pagination in my html file. Any solution would be great

Tags: django, django-pagination

html file

```
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                 
                  <button method="post" type="submit" class="action-btn checkRequired Submit" name="action" value="Submit"> previous</button>
                  <input type="hidden" name="page_no" value="{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">
                  {% endif %}


                  Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
 

                  {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                  <button method="post" type="submit" class="action-btn checkRequired Submit" name="action" value="Submit"> next</button>
                  <input type="hidden" name="page_no" value="{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">    
                  {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def practise(request):
        print(request)
        questions_list = Question.objects.get_queryset().order_by('id')
        
        paginator = Paginator(questions_list, 1) 
        page_number = request.POST.get('page_no')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        print(request.GET)
       
        if request.method=="POST":
                answer = request.POST.get('answer')
                difficulty = request.POST.get('myRange')
                surety=request.POST.get('surety')
              
            
        return render(request, "try.html", {'page_obj': page_obj})
```

Here, I have declared the next and previous button values(links), but after clicking on the Previous button, it is rendering to the next page instead of the previous. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use POST requests while working with pagination, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30516076/19041876) to learn why.

With GET requests, your code should look something like this :

```
def practice(request):
    question_list = Question.objects.get_queryset().order_by('id')
    paginator = Paginator(question_list, 1)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    
    if request.method=="POST":
        
        # Maybe verify the validity of your post data
        
        answer = request.POST.get('answer')
        difficulty = request.POST.get('myRange')
        surety=request.POST.get('surety')
        
        # Do something
        
        # HttpResponseRedirect to another url
        
    return render(request, 'try.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})
```

If you wanna use buttons, you can do like so in your template, or else with link you can follow [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/pagination/).

```
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"><button> Previous</button></a>
{% endif %}

Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}

{% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"><button> Next</button></a>  
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps !