# Laravel: Passing data through a controller results in MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760585/laravel-throwing-methodnotallowedhttpexception) post, however I don't believe it is relevant to my issue because I believe I am correctly passing post data through a post route.

Here is the relevant route code:

```
Route::get('/pass', 'PageController@pass');
Route::post('/pass/{request}',['uses' => 'PageController@passController']);
```

I would like to have one controller method for the 'pass' page, but to isolate the issue I have separated them.

Here are the relevant methods in PageController.php:

```
public function pass(){

    return view('pass')->with(array(
        'title'=>'Create A Pass'
    ));



}
public function passRequest($request){
    $data['request'] = $request;
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'studentID' => 'required|max:255',
        'teacherID' => 'required|max:255',
        'destination' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }
    $pass = new Pass;
    $pass->student = DB::table('users')->where('studentID', $request->studentID)->first()->id;
    $pass->teacher = DB::table('users')->where('teacherID', $request->teacherID)->first()->id;
    $pass->destination = $request->destination;
    $pass->save();
    return view('home')->with(array(
        'title'=>'Home',
        'success'=>'null'
    ));
}
```

I used the method stated [here](http://laravel.io/forum/07-26-2014-routing-passing-parameters-to-controller) in order to pass data to the controller. If this is bad practice/obsolete I'm open to any suggestions.

This is the form in the 'pass' page responsible for sending the post data

```
<form action="{{ url('pass') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="studentID">Student ID</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input id="studentID" name="studentID" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="teacherID">Teacher ID</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input id="teacherID" name="teacherID" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="destination">Destination</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input id="destination" name="destination" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Create Pass
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

On submission of this form I get the MethodNotAllowedHttpException Exception.

If a stack trace of the error would be helpful, please let me know. If there are any suggestions on style, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 2):

This form tag will generate a POST request to the URL `/pass`:

```
<form action="{{ url('pass') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

Your routes file does not allow that. It only allows GET requests to that url, but POST requests to `/pass/{request}`.

Not sure if its just a copy/paste mistake, but your POST route is set up to call `PageController@passController` method, but the method you shared from your controller is named `passRequest`. Those will need to match also.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I'm starting to understand the whole routing process. I neglected to connect the get method and {request} variable. Rather than understanding what I was doing I just was copy and pasting example code and using it for that purpose. I can't say it's working yet, at least this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Jeff Lambert pointed out, you should not put the `{request}` variable in the route.

You should remove that and have laravel inject the `Request` object for you.

Import the `Request` class if you haven't already at the top of the class.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

And your function should look like the following...

```
public function passRequest(Request $request)
{
    ...
}
```

If you have additional parameters to pass through the URL, then you may add them to the route, and add the arguments to the method after `Request $request`.  Laravel will figure out what to do with it.

Comment: This answer really helped me connect the reason for that {request} variable in the url of the route. Of course it's only for get, because that's where get responses go. Still working out a few issues in my code, but this really helped me connect the dots. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
Route::post('/pass/post','PageController@passController')->name('post_insert');
```

in your html form change to ...

```
<form action="{{ route('post_insert') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

change it also ...

```
public function passRequest(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
....
```