# getting error while redirecting back to a page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form with "email" field. If the email field is blank then I want to redirect back to the same form with the alert message. I have tried the code

```
return Redirect::back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
```

It gets redirected to the desired page but i am getting **MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:** this error. I am getting the alert message as desired once i click on the back button of the browser. How to resolve this?

Comment: I think you are getting that error because you are POSTing to a GET route. for clarifications [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760585/laravel-throwing-methodnotallowedhttpexception)

Comment: I have described the functions in the route.php as this:  Route::get('dramareport', 'ReportsController@dramareport'); Route::post('d_report', 'ReportsController@d_report');  I refereed to the link as you shown but i didn't get the idea.

Comment: In which url you are getting the error? is it `/dramareport` ?

Comment: What is your form `action` attribute content?

Comment: {!! Form::open(['url' => 'send_mail', 'class' => 'form-horizontal','onsubmit'=>'myFunction()']) !!} this is how i have declared the form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116371/discussion-between-prajakta-and-maraboc).

Answer (score 0):

You can return the errors like this also

```
return Redirect::to('/yout/path/here/')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
```