# ajax form Method errors in laravel 5.4

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Them I click the subscribe button it gives me error messages below

MethodNotAllowedHttpException

but I already define the method in the route file

```
Route::post('/emailsub','EmailSubController@emailsub');
```

The Controller Part are here

```
public function emailsub(Request $request){
    $data = new EmailSub;
    $data->email = $request->email;
    $data->save();
    return $request->all();;
}
```

Here is the Html Code Of my form

```
 <form method="POST" >
        {{csrf_field()}}
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="email" required="">

            <input type="submit" id="subbtn" value="Subscribe">          

     </form>
```

Here Is the Ajax part

```
  $('.button').on('click','#subbtn',function(){

           $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: "emailsub",
                  data:{
                      'email':$('#email').val(),
                      '_token':$(input['name=_token']),
                  },
                  success: function (data) {
                      $('#subbtn').val("Unsubscribe");
                  },
              });

    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760585/laravel-throwing-methodnotallowedhttpexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the ajax to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "/emailsub",
    data:{
        'email':$('#email').val(),
        '_token':$('input["name=_token"]').val(),
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#subbtn').val("Unsubscribe");
    },
});
```

You weren't putting the value of the crsf field in and the url should have a leading slash.

Comment: It Still Give Me The Same Error

Comment: Try changing the event listener: `$('#subbtn').on('click' ,function(e){`. I don't see a class `button` anywhere in your html. Also add `e.preventDefault()` before you send the ajax off.

Comment: One more problem I noticed, missing quotes in the token selector, should be: `'_token':$('input["name=_token"]').val()`

Answer (score 0):

Type: String
An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.
Try using method instead of type. method not allowed means it does not see the request as post request.

Comment: Problem not Solved