# MethodNotAllowedHttpException this wont let me insert the data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm just trying to insert title and body using eloquent on database and MethodNotAllowedHttpException appears wont let me do it cause of that error

Here's the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, array(
                'title' => 'required|max:255',
                'body' => 'required'
            ));

        $post = new Post; 

        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->body = $request->body;

        $post->save();

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);

    }
```

Here's my view create.blade.php

```
<form action="post.store" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Enter title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="body">Body</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="body" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn pull-right" value="post">
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you got your route setup correctly?  It may not allow Post requests.

Comment: can you show your route too @Lestah

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19760585/6521116)

Answer (score 3):

i am assuming your are using resource route.

i think this `<form action="post.store" method="POST">` should be `<form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="POST">` and use this too `{{ csrf_field() }}` inside form otherwise you will get tokenmismatch error.

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Enter title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="body">Body</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="body" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn pull-right" value="post">
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: yes your right im using resource on route i've tried {{ route('post.store') }} and put {{ csrf_field() }} inside form and i got a new error ErrorException

Route [post.store] not defined.

Comment: in console use the command `php artisan route:list` and check weather `post.store` is correct or not

Comment: but here its `<form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="POST">` just update it `<form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="POST">` it should work fine.

Comment: After you have made a change in your `web.php`, it is good to always do a `php artisan route:cache` to refresh the routes. See if you are still facing `[post.store]` error?

Answer (score 0):

You may use command `php artisan route:list` and in column **Name** you will see route name and you will be able to call in view by `{{ route('routename') }}`

Example: 
In route list is shown `posts.store`, so you will call in view `{{ route('posts.store') }}`

I think you may call incorrect route by above route view is `posts.show` but when insert you called `post.store` maybe `posts.store`

Comment: i always use php artisan route:list on my terminal to check the route names im sure of posts.store im looking rightnow on my list of routes

Comment: but I saw your create.blade.php is `post.store` not `posts.store` as your mention. should use with double curly bracket `{{ route('posts.store') }}`

Answer (score 0):

use in form action `{{ route('posts.store') }}`