# MethodNotAllowedHttpException - No message

Tags: laravel

I have a problem. Log in, registration is working but when I want to log out I get this error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException - No message

Error link: http://gazeta1.nazwa.pl/mesiek/error.html

Comment: share your sample code, or what you tried that gave you the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760585/laravel-throwing-methodnotallowedhttpexception)

Answer (score 1):

Method not allowed on logout route possibly means you are calling /logout via a get request (normal /logout link), whereas the logout request is meant to be called via post.

Here's a logout code snippet from the default laravel app when you create a new project

```
<a href="{{ url('logout')}}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
    <i class="icon-key"></i> Log Out 
</a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

The actual logout is called via a hidden form and the link just submits the form.

But i'm not certain since you did not include any code or details in your question

Answer (score 0):

try setting your .env file set

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

and run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

from your CLI hopes this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I used get and post methods instead of each other. for example, instead of get user's data, use post method.