# Laravel: MethodNotAllowedHttpException only on production server

Tags: php, http, post, laravel-5, http-verbs

I have read [laravel throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760585/laravel-throwing-methodnotallowedhttpexception) and I know that this error often appears when one is POSTing to a GET route, but I am really sure that I am POSTing to a POST route.

Also this does work on my locale Homestead version but its not working on my apache production server.

There is nothing in the Laravel log file.

This is the error:

[image]

If one takes a closer look there is `GET` and `POST`, I am not sure if something is wrong with the request:

[image]

This is start of the from from the blade file (I am not using JS, its a pure HTML based form):

```
<form action='/users/update/' method='post' id='contactForm'>

                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <h2>
                @lang('list.memb_4')
                <input type="submit" class="savebutton" id='contactButton' value="@lang('list.default_41')"></h2>
```

Any suggestion what could cause this error?

Comment: Maybe you're blocking POST on the .htaccess, did you check?

Comment: Don't you have any redirects from url with slash to url without slash? It can be the reason of the post requst problems.

Comment: can you show your routes file code, it may possible you accept only get request for this route.

Comment: Please post you `web.php`. Are you trying to update a single user?

Comment: @Pavel THANK YOU! That was it! A tiny slash prevented everything.... Omg. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to change

```
<form action='/users/update/' method='post' id='contactForm'>
```

to

```
<form action='/users/update' method='post' id='contactForm'>
```

In my `web.php` file I also use

```
Route::post('/users/update', 'UserController@update');
```

I don't know why - but on my test server Homestead this was no problem, but on my production server this is a problem.