# How to post form data to store method?

Tags: php, angular6, laravel-5.6

I am trying to post form data from angular service to laravel controller store. I am using following code. The url I set is being called but I get following exception error:

```
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException"
```

These are the codes I am using.

```
private _commentUrl = GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL + 'comments/store';


postComment(data:any) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._commentUrl, data);
}
```

### php

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
```

Comment: Maybe help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760585/laravel-throwing-methodnotallowedhttpexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to mention store in your url

You can simply write your url like:

```
private _commentUrl = GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL + 'comments';
```

Answer (score 0):

MethodNotAllowedException means that you have not set the appropriate route in your web.php.

Add in your web.php

`Route::post('XXX', 'CommentsController@store')`