# Vue Laravel submit form using button in other component

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js

I have two components:

Header.vue:

```
<button type="submit" @click="clickNext">Next</button>
methods:{
    clickNext(){
        Bus.$emit('submitForm');
       }
    }
```

And Home.vue

```
<form method="POST" ref="my-form">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
</form>

  created() {
    Bus.$on('submitForm', () => this.$refs['my-form'].submit(this.send()))
  },
  methods: {
    send() {
       console.log("send!");
    }
  }
```

I need send form (with component Home.vue) using button which is in Header.vue component.
When I click Next button Laravel REFRESH PAGE and return error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>
> No message

Answer (score 0):

You have to have CSRF token in every form that does any method except GET.
Read on it in [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf)

Comment: I have CSRF token in blade and in this blade I have redirect to Vue: `<div id="app"></div>`

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760585/laravel-throwing-methodnotallowedhttpexception) be the case?