# Force Laravel Project to use HTTPS but APIs stopped working

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a Laravel project where I also run APIs for an APP.

After adding rewrite rules in .htaccess file my APIs of an APP stopped working.

```
#Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "stopped working"? What error are you seeing?

Comment: @ElementalStorm MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218: like this. And if I remove above lines from htaccess file then its working fine

Comment: Ok, you may want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760585/laravel-throwing-methodnotallowedhttpexception